# populate location javascript var from php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, google-maps-api-3

I have a MySQL database with lat and long entries. I'm trying to show these pair of lat long as marker.

The google maps locations javascript is given as:

```
var locations = [{lat: 36.53256989, lng: -6.29461908},
{lat: 36.76487732, lng: -5.77446127},
{lat: 36.50241470, lng: -6.27566910},
{lat: 36.53186417, lng: -6.29524183},
{lat: 40.42653275, lng: -3.70984125},
{lat: 52.24983978, lng: 21.00909996} ]
```

But I retrieve lat and long from a SQL query.

How can I populate this locations variable with a `json_enconde`, how I should build it up the php array?

I have tried things like this:

```
 <script>
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT name, lat, lon FROM restaurants";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $labels = [];
    $locations = [];
    while($row = $result->fetch_array())
    {
        $labels[] = $row['name'];
        $locations[] = array($row['lat'], $row['lon']);
    }
    ?>
  var labels = <?php echo json_encode($labels);?>;
  var locations = <?php echo json_encode($locations);?>;
</script>
```

but the javascript var location given with this procedure is like that:

```
var locations = [["36.53256989","-6.29461908"],["36.76487732","-5.77446127"],["36.50241470","-6.27566910"],["36.53186417","-6.29524183"],["40.42653275","-3.70984125"],["52.24983978","21.00909996"]];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps

Comment: have tried it, but i have not success, the location array isn't build properly.

Comment: @cramopy I haven't asking for a coding service. I only have aske how I should build the php array to get an array as expected when json_encode is used

Comment: @manespgav yeah then first of all include all your code in a `Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example` because at the moment I can't see any `php` code nor an error message which states that `location array isn't build properly`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your syntax in order to get the expected results. You have to change

```
array($row['lat'], $row['lon'])
```

to

```
(object)array(
    'lat' => floatval($row['lat']),
    'lng' => floatval($row['lon'])
)
```

Explanation:

- why `(object)`: you previously provided an array (in json `[]`), but in the result you want it as an object (in json `{}`). Simply type cast it to an object.
- why `floatval`: you previously had the values as an `string` but you wanted it as a `double`/`float`. Just use the given parsing method.
- why `'lat'=>`: your resulting object should have the key `lat`, so you really have to save the data at the key `lat`
- why `'lng'=>`: same as at point above